# For what z is f differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

I just need some clarification:

Let $f(z)=\bar{z}-1$, for what $z$ is $f$ differentiable.

I know from the CR equations that $\bar{z}$ is not differentiable anywhere, and likewise with $\bar{z}-1$.  However, if we let $z=\bar{z}$, then isn't $f(\bar{z})=z-1$ differentiable.  My question is how do we figure out all values of $z$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your title does not make any sense.  There is no such that as a differentiable complex number.

Comment: I want to say...for...none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in saying $f(z)=\overline{z}-1$ is not differentiable anywhere. However your second to last sentence doesn't make sense to me, and you don't need it to state where $f$ is differentiable. When showing that the Cauchy-Riemann Equations for $f$ do not hold for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, you are saying that $f$ isn't differentiable for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$.